# How do I associate a Docker image layer's hash at push time with the Dockerfile line that created it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to figure out which Dockerfile line is creating a layer that is particularly big and gets rebuilt and/or re-pushed too often. When running `docker push`, it lists hashes for all the layers together with a size and progress bar, so it's easy to idenfity which layer is the problem at push time. I was hoping then that `docker history` would help tie that to the Dockerfile... It does have the `CREATED BY` column that has the Dockerfile command for each layer. However, there's no hash listed for any of the layers, except the last / top-most one. All the other ones are listed as `<missing>`.

So, how do I link a layer's hash at `docker push` time with the Dockerfile command that created it, if `docker history` is not the answer? Thanks.

Comment: An example of the kind of info I would have liked to know earlier: ids during pull are different from those of the various layers in storage, because the former correspond to SHA256 of the compressed layers, while the latter are SHA256 of the layer without compression. https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/